# How can I find the 'public absolute' path of a file?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-tinymce

**Short Version**

I need to give in the absolute path of a Javascript file that is to be hooked into something. It works if I hardcode it into

'http://mywebsite.com/folder/script.js'

However I prefer not to hardcode it in. I can do `dirname(___FILE___)`, which gives me this:

'/home/public_html/folder/script.js'

But that fails, the script isn't loaded. What's the best practice to find the absolute path (starting with 'http://')?

-

**Long Version**

On [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons) in the Wordpress documentation relating to the tinyMCE plugin creation, I found this:

```
// Load the TinyMCE plugin : editor_plugin.js (wp2.5)
function add_myplugin_tinymce_plugin($plugin_array) {
   $plugin_array['myplugin'] = URLPATH.'tinymce/editor_plugin.js';
   return $plugin_array;
}
```

There's a note at the bottom saying:

> Note: when using the mce_external_plugins filter, the url should point
>   to the actual plugin file, as in the example above.

A bit higher in the documentation they say

> mce_external_plugins: passes in/out an associative php array
>   'plugin_name' => 'plugin_url'. The url should be absolute and on the
>   same domain as your WordPress installation.

I am completely puzzled because I can't find any information about **'URLPATH'** which is used in their example. I don't think it exists in PHP, WP or TinyMCE, but I could be wrong.

Incidentally, were this to be an error in the WP documentation, what would I replace URLPATH with to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your resource is included in your Plugin:

- `plugins_url()` is the URL to `\wp-content\plugins\` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url))

So if you have a .js file in `\wp-content\plugins\plugin-slug\file.js`:

`<?php echo plugins_url() . '\plugin-slug\file.js'; ?>`

**BUT WAIT!!**

If your purpose is *actually* to load a javascript file, you actually want to *enqueue* that file, using `wp_enqueue_script()`, hooked into the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

And `wp_enqueue_script()` uses the *filepath* rather than the *URL*, so you could use `dirname(___FILE___)` if that' what you're comfortable with.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the parameters to plugins_url(), so it will determine the plugin name too? I once read that plugins should keep working, even if the site owner changes the individual plugin folder name.

Comment: fixed it with: plugins_url( '' , __FILE__ );  thanks both

Comment: You should use the first parameter too instead of string operations. plugins_url('script.js',\_\_FILE\_\_); for example.